# Robots.txt flexibility with top level domains

Tags: parsing, python-3.x, web-crawler, python-3.4, robots.txt

so the only problem I have left for this web crawler is making it to where when the top level domain changes, say from imdb to youtube, that it will then switch the robots.txt from following the disallow rules of imdb to youtube. I believe that it can all be fixed just with how the variables are declared in the beginning.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
re.IGNORECASE = True

#SourceUrl
url = "http://www.imdb.com"

urls = [url]

visited =[url]

robotsUrl = url +'/robots.txt'


while len(urls) < 250000:
        try:
            htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
            robots = urllib.request.urlopen(robotsUrl).read()
            disallowList = re.findall(b'Disallow\:\s*([a-zA-Z0-9\*\-\/\_\?\.\%\:\&]+)', robots)
        except:
            print (urls[0])

        sourceCode = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, "html.parser")
        urls.pop(0)
        print(len(urls))
        for link in sourceCode.findAll('a', href=True):
            if "http://" not in link['href']:
                link['href'] = urllib.parse.urljoin(url,link['href'])
            in_disallow = False
            for i in range(len(disallowList)):
                if (disallowList[i]).upper().decode() in link['href'].upper():
                    in_disallow = True
                    break
            if not in_disallow:
                if link['href'] not in visited:
                    urls.append(link['href'])
                    visited.append(link['href'])
print (visited)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the domain names used inside your `robots.txt` matches the one corresponding to the url to your `robots.txt`, it is all fine. In other words, you can replace `yoursite.imdb` to `yoursite.youtube` in all urls. That's fine.

**Update**

Say you have a sitemap declared in your robots.txt, then it should have the same tld.

http://www.yoursite.imbd/robots.txt

should contain:

sitemap: http://www.yoursite.imbd/sitemap1.xml (not .youtube)

Otherwise, for directives such as allow or disallow, there is not impact, since the TDL does not appear in the paths.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you provide a sample code, I don't quite catch on to what you are saying.